# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '203' of undefined

Tags: javascript

```
    var wins = [] ;
    for(var i=0; i<11; i++){
        wins[i] = [] ;
        for(var j=0;j<11; j++){
        wins[i][j] = [] ;}}

    var count = [] ;

    for(var i=0; i<11; i++){
        for(var j=0; j<7; j++){
            for(var k=0; k<5; k++){

            wins[i][j+k][count] = true;
    }
    count++ ;
}}

    for(var i=0; i<11; i++){
        for(var j=0; j<7; j++){
            for(var k=0; k<5; k++){
                wins[j+k][i][count] = true;
    }
    count++ ;
}}

    for(var i=0; i<7; i++){
        for(var j=0; j<7; j++){
            for(var k=0; k<5; k++){
                wins[i+k][j+k][count] = true;
            }
            count++ ;
        }
    }

    for(var i=0; i<7; i++){
        for(var j=14; j>3; j--){
            for(var k=0; k<5; k++){
                wins[i+k][j-k][count] = true;
            }
            count++ ;
        } }
```

i get the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '203' of undefined.
how  can i fix it?
i get error in last for loop.
i'm newbie in java script.

Comment: The error means that `wins[i+k][j-k]` does not evaluate to anything when count has reached 203.

Comment: What are you trying to loop over and why do you have almost the same code 5 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Preliminary note** :

What you want to achieve is not clear, and in my opinion you shouldn't need all these arrays. The better solution would be to redesign your code entirely, but in order to help you with that part, you would need to explain what is the actual goal and problem you are trying to solve with your code.

However, in the following answer I'll try to give you guidance on how you can debug and understand your own code, which I hope will help you anticipate and think more clearly about your code before you write it.

---

As general guideline in this kind of problems, where you are manipulating a lot of arrays :

What is likely to happen is that you forgot to define a value in one of your arrays, or you are trying to access an index larger than the array.

e.g:

```js
     let arr = []

     arr[0] = 10;
     arr[2] = 42;
     
     console.log(`Length of array is : ${arr.length}`);
     
     
     for (let i in [0,1,2,3]) {
         console.log(arr[i]);
     }
```

So, you could debug your code by

- print the arrays in console to check where you might have forgotten to define a value
- Check that the indices you use are not larger that the size of your arrays.

---

For your particular code :

triple for loops don't help to see clearly what happens.

It's a bit difficult to propose something else since you didn't explain the goal of your program, but in general I would try to **not** having so many complicated loops with calculations in the indices.

Having a loop with j decreasing from 14 to 4, in between two other loops with k and i, with things like [j-k] as index is likely to cause trouble, even to the most experienced JavaScript coders.

To debug your program, I would recommend you to print the indices in the console to understand what happens :

**Example for the last part of your code** (but you should do the same with the other parts)

```js
    for(var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        for(var j = 14; j > 3; j--) {
            for(var k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
                console.log(`wins[${i+k}][${j-k}]`);
            }
        }
    }
```

Check that these are really the one you wanted to access, and that you correctly defined them previously.

Comment: And, better yet, use `.forEach()` on your arrays to completely do away with having to maintain and reference indexes.